# react-native-admob-native-ads onPress Ad App crash in React native

Tags: react-native, crash, admob

[image]

I faced the same issue and none of these helped me. In my case the issue caused by "onPress ad my app is crash please help."

Answer (score -1):

Try to wrap your function with try/catch and catch exception in your developer tools to analyze a problem

```js
const onPressAdBlockBanner = useCallback(() => {
  try {
    // do my logic
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}, []);
```